# Update php select list using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multi-select

Im New to Ajax and PHP.

I would like to update my php selectlist( which is populated from the file lastlog) using ajax.Im new to ajax and php.Im trying to use  onclick javascript action to update my php select list contents from different file

```
function selectlist()
  {
    $count    = count(file('/var/www/php/userAccount/UserDeactivator/lastlog'));
    $userlist = file('/var/www/php/userAccount/UserDeactivator/lastlog');
    $option   = '';
    $options .= "<option disabled  =CSL>UserID(Total $count Inactive Users)</option>";
    foreach ($userlist as $ong)
      {
        $options .= '<option>' . $ong . '</option>';
      } //$userlist as $ong
    $select = '<select name="Category[]" multiple="multiple"  size="10">' . $options . '</select>';
    // $select = '<select name=''>'.$options.'</select>';
    echo $select;
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue or problem? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Pls help me in framing ajax query to post data to the select list options when java script onclick event is initiated

Comment: i need client side script to update my selectlist contents

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posing a question like this is hard for us to help. You need to post some of the code you have tried to use. This PHP code is not enough to go off of. What HTML do you have so far? What JavaScript or JQuery do you have? Please edit your post and add these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your PHP code looks a bit off. You define `$option` and then append to `$options` which does not appear to be defined.

```
<?php
function selectlist(){
    $count = count(file('/var/www/php/userAccount/UserDeactivator/lastlog'));
    $userlist = file('/var/www/php/userAccount/UserDeactivator/lastlog');
    $options = '';
    $options .= "<option disabled  =CSL>UserID(Total $count Inactive Users)</option>";
    foreach($userlist as $ong) {
        $options .= '<option>' . $ong . '</option>';
    } //$userlist as $ong
    $select = '<select name="Category[]" multiple="multiple"  size="10">' . $options . '</select>';
    // $select = '<select name=''>'.$options.'</select>';
    echo $select;
}
?>
```

I think that is what you mean to do.
Now I am a fan of JQuery, so I will give you a guess here. Since you did not post any details about your form, it's all my best guess and is untested.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#action").click(function(){
        $.get("getSelect.php", function(data){
            $("#dynSelect").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="action" class="button">Get Log List</a>
<div id="dynSelect"></div>
```